# AmazonECS php not finding products when code moved to alternate domain

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

I'm running AmazonECS.class.php on a site, but when I copy the code over to a new website, the api returns no results for the same search string that works on the first site. The api seems to be working, I can var_dump the $response and it has all the fields, but the results are "nothing found".

Are the AWS_API_KEY or AWS_API_SECRET_KEY tied to a domain? Do I have to apply for new ones, and if I do, will the old ones still work?

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly, the problem was that the search texts *were* different in a small way. The one that worked spelled out a state name and the one that didn't used a state abbreviation. It fails on a manual search on Amazon's website also.  Why on earth isn't their search more robust and fuzzy?